# Arrow function in Typescript not recognized in string interpolation (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, arrow-functions

When Arrow function is used in TypeScript for String interpolation, there is no output in the browser with expected content "Hello" and there is no error as well. But it displays when normal function syntax is used. Why so?

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  getStr: () => 'Hello';
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<p>{{ getStr() }}</p>
```

Comment: specify the error..

Comment: @GouravGarg, Sorry for not being clear. Updated the question with details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to `getStr = () => 'Hello';` as you need to initialize getStr.

if you want to add typing as well, you can do so :
`getStr: () => string = () => "Hello";`